# How is this program finding its values?

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = "8!2, 4!2, 9!3, 12!4";
var b = a.split(",")

console.log(b);
var c = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {

  var d = b[i].split("!");
  c = c + d[0] / d[1];
}

console.log(c);
```

I kind of understand what the code is trying to do but I fall off when it comes to c = c + d[0] / d[1]
the output gives 12, but I'm not entirely sure how this was calculated.

It splits everything using commas in variable a, so I get 8!2, 4!2, etc in the console logs, then it splits b[i] with "!" and I now have [0] and [1], 0 index returns 8, 4, 9, 12, etc and 1 index returns 2, 2, 3, 4

then the for loop calculates c = c + d[0] / d[1], my question then is what value is being calculated here from index 0 and 1?
I am supposed to get 12, but I'm not entirely sure how this was achieved in the code. Any help would be highly appreciated, I'm incredibly new to programming in general so a simple explanation would be more than enough for me. :)

Comment: each "pair" is divided then added to c... `(8/2) + (4/2) + (9/3) + (12/4) = 12`. the `c` is being used to total all the divisions for each loop. the `D[0]` and `D[1]` is the result of the `!` split for each pair. here try this... `console.log(b[i]);`

Comment: If you don't mind, I've put your code into an embed so we can run it here.

Comment: does this run without error? `b[i].split('!')` will return an array of strings. Shouldn't it be parsed to int using `parseInt()`?

Comment: @AbrarHossain, it works without `parseInt`, because of the `/` operator which converts the operands to number.

Comment: this is an excellent example of why variable names `a` `b` `c` `d` `i` `j` `n` all should be avoided, especially if it's code attempting to illustrate a concept to others.....

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the correct result!
 it first splits the 'a' by comma and you will have 4 items in the d variable, then it sums up the divide result of each number set:

```
 c=c + 8/2; //c=4
   c=4+4/2;//c=6
   c=6+9/3;//c=9
  c=9+12/4;//c=12
```

that's why you get 12

Answer (score 0):

At least, you add the fractions of the given string.

```js
function start() {
    var stringOfFractions = "8!2, 4!2, 9!3, 12!4",
        fractions = stringOfFractions.split(/,\s+/),
        sum = 0,
        index;

    for (index = 0; index < fractions.length; index++) {
        let [numerator, denominator] = fractions[index].split("!");
        sum += numerator / denominator;
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = sum;
}

window.onload = start;
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: "How is this program finding its values?"

Comment: through text. the power of word, the prosa. and the understanding how splitting works.

Answer (score -1):

The thing that you failed to notice was either the operational precedence (division is precedent over addition) or how variable c has an imperatively altered state that persists between iterations, acting as an accumulator.

Maybe i'll try a functional-programming-inspired approach to explaining this that i'm not too sure of

a sequence of pairs (8,2), (4,2), (9,3), (12,4)
that for each we want just a/b

is equivalent to

a sequence of numeric values 4.0 2.0 3.0 3.0

So we have

1. a numeric value 0 that we want to add each of
   a sequence of numeric values 4.0 2.0 3.0 3.0
2. a numeric value 4.0 that we want to add each of
   a sequence of numeric values 2.0 3.0 3.0
3. a numeric value 6.0 that we want to add each of
   a sequence of numeric values 3.0 3.0
4. a numeric value 9.0 that we want to add each of
   a sequence of numeric values [ 3.0 ]
5. a numeric value 12.0

(edit: oh darn i didnt notice the comments made similar explanations, should i delete…)